# svg image tag size

Tags: html, svg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
       <svg 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        id="test1" 
        height="1000px" 
        width="1000px">
            <image id="testimg1" xlink:href="http://localhost/at/src/html5test/map1.png" width="87" height="66" x="0" y="0"/>

        </svg>
        </p>        
    </body>
</html>
```

within the image tag, is it a must to state the  width="87" height="66"? i want to let the image to display its original size(e.g the original size is  width="180" height="120"), is it to possible to do that ?

in this case, if i remove width="87" height="66", the whole svg will display nothing.

```
<svg 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    id="test1" 
    height="1000px" 
    width="1000px">
        <image id="testimg1" xlink:href="http://localhost/at/src/html5test/1.svg" x="0" y="0"  />
        <image id="testimg2" xlink:href="http://localhost/at/src/html5test/2.svg" x="19" y="127" />
        <image id="testimg3" xlink:href="http://localhost/at/src/html5test/3.svg" x="130" y="110"  />            

    </svg>
```

thanks

Comment: Your question is poorly worded. For instance what is the images original size and why aren't you using it already (do you even know it)? Are you looking for a relative size or an absolute one? What are you trying to achieve? Have you looked at the specification or tried it without the attributes?

Comment: the original size means the image dimension of that file

Comment: Still unclear. Why haven't you changed width="87" to width="120"? Are you trying to say there are a range of different images with different dimensions that you don't know in advance?

Comment: @spliFF yes, width & height is unknown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to understand that the width and height are the bounds of the image viewport, not the "size" of the image. Put another way those values are the MAXIMUM area that image should occupy. If a raster (bitmap) image turns out to be smaller or larger than that area then the scaling and positioning are controlled by the [preserveAspectRatio](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute. If you don't set width and height they default to 0 which is why you aren't seeing anything. The spec says:

> An ‘image’ element establishes a new viewport for the referenced file
>   as described in Establishing a new viewport.  The bounds for the new
>   viewport are defined by attributes ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘width’ and ‘height’. The
>   placement and scaling of the referenced image are controlled by the
>   ‘preserveAspectRatio’ attribute on the ‘image’ element.

So the solution you're looking for is to set the width/height to the maximum area you expect an image to fill and then set preserveAspectRatio to the appropriate value to set the scale and position the way you want (the spec provides an example SVG showing some of the possible behaviours for preserveAspectRatio).

Comment: preserveAspectRatio allows us to do the css-equivalent of 'background-size: contain' c.q. 'background-size: cover'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: A codepen to demonstrate SpliFF's answer (and my previous comment :) ) http://codepen.io/ideogram/pen/apWLNG