# How to force an image displayed with SVG element to cover the entire width and height

Tags: html, svg

I have generated a blurred image using `svg` element. I want it to cover the entire width and height of the screen.

Now to better understand I am providing two fiddles below and at last what result I am wanting to achieve :

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2w52czh/1/) - **Image is blurred, but it doesn't cover the entire screen**

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgarsae9/) - **Image is not blurred, but it covers the entire screen**

> **Result I want : Image should be blurred (like *Fiddle1*) and also it should cover entire screen (like *Fiddle2*)**

**HTML Code to blur image in the first fiddle :**

```
<svg class="blur" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
    <filter id="filter">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
    </filter>
    <image xlink:href="https://saudiwoman.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/crowded-restaurant.jpg" filter="url(#filter)"></image>
</svg>
```

**To be clear again I want image to cover the entire screen like fiddle2 *and* to be blurred too.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [svg image tag size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407069/svg-image-tag-size)

Comment: @taxicala  I don't find any answer in that post .Can you pls answer or specify where exactly the answer is ?

Comment: This demo I made looks close - it imitates `top center / cover` : http://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/vEzqoX.

Comment: @Shikkediel thanks.It helped .You can post it as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: 1. Convert the jpeg to a data uri, 2. replace the image in the svg file with that data uri version, 3. convert the svg to either a URI or base 64 encode it, 4. use that SVG image as the background image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the dimensions of the image ahead of time, you can use the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` SVG attributes and skip the JavaScript altogether. In [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15xwwr3q/) it appears that you have to specify the image's `width` and `height` explicitly as well for this to work.

```
<svg class="blur" viewBox="0 0 4288 2848" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
  <filter id="filter">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
  </filter>
  <image xlink:href="https://saudiwoman.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/crowded-restaurant.jpg" filter="url(#filter)"
    width="4288" height="2848"></image>
</svg>
```

Another option is to specify the image as the SVG element's background [in CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/ym02onbu/1/), blurring with the [filter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Comment: Very nice solution that I'll have to keep in mind. The option to use a background and blur with CSS would be lacking cross browser support, I believe. But +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to have made something similar with jQuery a while back - a blurred `svg` with an `<image>` inside it that has the same behaviour as if it were given a `center top / cover` background. It uses the aspect ratio of the container (with `overflow: hidden`) and compares it to the ratio of the image to make it adapt to either full height or width of the wrapper element. When the parent is relatively narrower than the image itself, a transform is used to center the image horizontally :

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5d95t0jf/)

```
<div id="wrap">
  <svg id="blur">
    <filter id="filter">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>
    <image xlink:href="//saudiwoman.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/crowded-restaurant.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#filter)"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tall {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```
$(function() {

var parent = $('#wrap'),
scene = $('#blur'),
ratio = 4288/2848; // aspect ratio of the image

$(window).on('load resize', coverSpace);

function coverSpace() {

    var range = parent.width(),
    term = parent.height(),
    proportion = range/term;

    if (proportion >= ratio) scene.css({width: '100%', height: range/ratio}).removeAttr('class');
    else scene.css({width: term*ratio, height: term}).attr('class', 'tall');
}
});
```

I've reduced this from the original demo which uses a small plugin that has creates animated blur. In this form it wouldn't be a big step to make it vanilla JS altogether, jQuery isn't that great at accessing `svg` anyway. But if it's on a site that's linked to the library already, it should work fine as is in any case.

Here's also a reduced case that will imitate `center center / cover` (with switching transforms) :

http://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/MaGbbp

---

Edit - and here's one for the purists :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var parent = document.getElementById('wrap'),
scene = document.getElementById('blur'),
ratio = 4288/2848;

window.addEventListener('load', coverSpace);

window.addEventListener('resize', coverSpace);

function coverSpace() {

    var range = parent.clientWidth,
    term = parent.clientHeight,
    proportion = range/term;

    if (proportion >= ratio) {
    scene.style.width = '100%';
    scene.style.height = range/ratio + 'px';
    scene.removeAttribute('class');
    }
    else {
    scene.style.width = term*ratio + 'px';
    scene.style.height = term + 'px';
    scene.setAttribute('class', 'tall');
    }
}
});
```