# SVG: make child element match width and height of parent using pixels, not percentages?

Tags: html, svg

In the code below, rootBox and imageBox1 are given the same dimensions. The image should cover the entire beige background.

Despite sharing the same width and height values, imageBox1 is smaller than rootBox.

How do you get imageBox1 to match rootBox using pixels (not percentages)?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REKWmJ

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg id="rootBox" width="500" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="beige" />

    <svg id="imageBox1" width="500" height="800">
       <image class="frame" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6njspwfz2hgfd03/iPhone_X_Black.png?raw=1" />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try height twice the value of width in both svg elements.

Comment: @swatchai thanks for the suggestion, but what is the principle here? is this the only way to make children elements match the size of parents?

Comment: I found that the image has aspect ratio =h/w= 2 (roughly), to preserve it and match both containers (svg is container) you simply put it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the preserveAspectRatio attribute to "none" fixes this. This answer provides more details as to why this problem occurred  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409554/10085266.

Comment: For other people with the same problem, the issue is the aspect ratio of the image doesn't match the container's aspect ratio, so SVG by default preserves the aspect ratio instead of matching the size you explicitly define.